# String building using += fails when expressions are used in ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This appears to be a bug in SQL Server. I've been able to reproduce it in 2017 and 2022. When using the += operator to build a string from a resultset, if there is an expression in the ORDER BY clause, it will only append the last row from the sorted resultset. The expected behavior is that it concatenates the value from each row returned in order. Observed behavior is that when there is any expression in the ORDER BY clause other than a column name, only the last value is concatenated to the string.

The below script illustrates the issue. I don't know how or where to report these sorts of things and I would like to verify this behavior is not as expected.

```
USE tempdb

GO

DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    A   INT IDENTITY
,   B   VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT @T (B)
SELECT value 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT('Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country.', ' ')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Start:
'
SELECT @SQL += B + '
'
    FROM @T

SELECT @SQL

--Works with ORDER BY without an expression
SET @SQL = 'Start:
'
SELECT @SQL += B + '
'
    FROM @T
    ORDER BY A

SELECT @SQL

--Fails with an expression in ORDER BY; only returns the last row. 
SET @SQL = 'Start:
'
SELECT @SQL += B + '
'
    FROM @T
    ORDER BY LEFT(B, 1)

SELECT @SQL

--Works with STRING_AGG
SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(B, '
') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEFT(B, 1))
    FROM @T

SELECT @SQL
```

Comment: This is by design. The `select @var = @var + 'string' from table` is not documented to work like you want it to work. Usually it works without ORDER BY but not with. You should upgrade your code to modern times, STRING_AGG or FOR XML

Comment: Adding to @siggemannen's comment, the behavior of aggregate string concatenation (`select @var = @var + 'string'`) is undefined because it's plan dependent.